# Update "hosts" file on CentOS server with cPanel

Tags: web-hosting, php, whm, centos

I'm migrating from an old server to a new server running cPanel/WHM v86.0.18 and I'm in the process of migrating and testing two websites, let's say example.com and web.example.com.
These two websites are currently hosted on the old server, both with the same IP, let's say 168.212.226.204. Obviously, the new server has a different IP, let's say 177.131.188.194, but the websites will have the same URL.

example.com will make a PHP cURL request to web.example.com to authenticate the users on both the websites, but the problem I'm facing is that the cURL request on the new server is going to web.example.com:168.212.226.204 instead of going to the new IP.
When I'm testing the websites on Windows, a simple edit to the hosts file will do the trick, but when I edit the /etc/hosts file in CentOS to point to the new IP, every cURL request fails and I can't even ping web.example.com without losing all the packets.

My question is: how can I reproduce the hosts file edit of Windows in CentOS?

Comment: cPanel usually means you are using shared hosting.  Is that the case?  If so, you shouldn't have access to edit `/etc/hosts`

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the PHP cURL library, but the `curl` command line has a `--resolve` flag that lets you change the IP address of the host for just that one call, not globally for the entire system.  It looks like you might be able to use something similar from PHP:  [curl --resolve equivalent in PHP CURL library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433016/curl-resolve-equivalent-in-php-curl-library)

Comment: Thanks for the answers @Stephen Ostermiller, I'm using cPanel and WHM but I'm not on a shared hosting. I own the CentOS server but it has cPanel and WHM installed. I will try with the `--resolve` option of `curl` and post the results here.